# "Too many values to unpack" when trying to write a code for length and width in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a code for L & W in Python. However, after I enter the L & W that is asks me to enter, it just gives me an error of "too many values to unpack" but I do not know what I may be doing wrong!

```
def main():
    l,w = input("Enter length and width:")
    result = rectangleAP(float(l), float(w))
    print("The area is", result[0])
    print("The perimeter is", result[1])

def rectangleAP(length, width):
    Area = length * width
    Perimeter = (length + width) * 2
    return [Area, Perimeter]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `input()` returns a string which contains as many characters as the use types in. Your code is very fragile. Perhaps you meant: `l,w = input("Enter length and width:").split(',')`

Comment: I’d have to check but I don’t think you can assign multiple variables to an input function, this might be the cause of the error. If not, could you paste the error traceback so we can help more effectively?

Comment: That was perfect! Thank you, I understand that now, I'll research a bit more on it! But it was driving me crazy

Answer (score 4):

The `input()` function returns a singular value, a string. However, you are trying to assign one value (the return value of `input()`) to two variables, `l` and `w`. So, you probably want to split the string at some delimiter using the `str.split()` method:

```py
length, width = input("Enter length and width ('length,width')").split(",")
```

Alternatively, you could do two `input()` calls:

```py
length, width = input("Enter the length:"), input("Enter the width:")
```

(Which could also be separated out into two lines.)

Comment: Thank you, just a random throw, but would you have any idea how the professor in my lab was able to execute it? He ran it through python tutor (with the exact code, without split), and I tried it through there too but I got the same error. However, on his lab tutorial screen when he does something similar, it was able to run. 

I guess blindly following is never good, but I just wanted to recreate the example to understand

Comment: There's a possibility he did two `input()` calls. For example, `length, width = input("Enter length:"), input("Enter width:")`.

Comment: Could the professor have been running Python version 2.x? Its input() function was quite different from the one in Python version 3.x.

Comment: @TurePålsson I have no experience with Python 2, so I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 1):

Taking input of length and width separately can help you,
As well as using .split() as suggest by @quamrana can also help to take input using a separator such as comma(',')

```
   def main():
        l = input("Enter length:")
        w = input("Enter width:")
        #or
        #l,w = input("Enter length and width:").split(',')
    
    result = rectangleAP(float(l), float(w))
    print("The area is", result[0])
    print("The perimeter is", result[1])

def rectangleAP(length, width):
    Area = length * width
    Perimeter = (length + width) * 2
    return [Area, Perimeter]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Closest thing to what your are trying to do:**
As Jacob Lee said, `input()` only returns one value, and you are giving it 2 variables to unpack.

**Answer:**

```
l, w = input("length: "), input("width")
```